# Using jsstore for fetching indexeddb data with where condition

Tags: angular, typescript, indexeddb

Using jsstore for fetching indexeddb data with where condition is filtering data and while returning as promise ,I cannot bind data in component
My service code

```
       GetArticleByIdFromIndexedDB=function(id,section)
         {let dbName:string;
          dbName=this.GetUrlAndDB(section,false,true);
           return new Promise<Article>
             ((resolve,reject)=>this._connection.select({
                            From:dbName,
                       Where:{
                       ArticleId:id
                       }
               },function(res)
                {
               resolve(res);
                },
                function(err)
               {
            reject(err);
               }
                 ));
```

called in component like

```
  this._service.GetArticleByIdFromIndexedDB(this.id,this.section).then(res=>
      { 
 this._articleDetail.ArticleId=res.ArticleId;
  this._articleDetail.HeadLine=res.HeadLine;

 this._articleDetail.Abstract=res.Abstract;

 this._articleDetail.ImageLink =this._article[0].ImageLink;
 }).catch(err=>{console.log(err);});
```

Binding in html like

```
             <img class="img-responsive" [src]="_articleDetail?.ImageLink" >
              <div class="img-hr-new"></div>
  <a [routerLink]="['/articledetail',_articleDetail?.ArticleId]"><h4>{{_articleDetail?.HeadLine}}</h4></a>
  <p>{{_articleDetail?.Abstract}}</p></div>


  </div>
```

Comment: Can you share your piece of code? I am not able to understand what is wrong there without that information.

Comment: The result you get from the `select` method is always in a form of array of objects so you should write like `res[0].ArticleId` instead of `res.ArticleId` and similarly for other properties too

Comment: this._articleDetail.ArticleId=res[0].ArticleId;
      this._articleDetail.HeadLine=res[0].HeadLine;
            this._articleDetail.Abstract=res[0].Abstract;
       changed like this.not yet working

Comment: Are you sure you are getting result in OnSuccess. Can you tell me what is the output you are getting there?

Comment: Another thing, you are not using bracket "{" after => in service code. Can you add "{" there and see if this is fixed.

Comment: Its working fine thanks

Comment: Good to know. May i know what has happened?

Comment: missed { in service code.I realized that after your suggestion.thanks